# Post request always wrapped by optional text

Tags: php, xcode, swift, http-post, option-type

I have a very similar problem like in [Why the http post request body always wrapped by Optional text in the Swift app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149368/why-the-http-post-request-body-always-wrapped-by-optional-text-in-the-swift-app)
but I can´t apply the solution from this thread to my code, because I don´t have a request.setValue.
Does anyone know what I need to do to get rid of the Optional?
My Code:

```
 @IBAction func LoginButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    let username = UsernameTextField.text
    let password = PasswordTextField.text

    if(username!.isEmpty || password!.isEmpty) {return; }



    let request = NSMutableURLRequest (URL: NSURL(string: "http://myip/loginregister.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        let data = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!



        do {
            if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                let success = json["success"] as? Int                                  // Okay, the `json` is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                print("Success: \(success)")
            } else {
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)    // No error thrown, but not NSDictionary
                print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
            }
        } catch let parseError {
            print(parseError)                                                          // Log the error thrown by `JSONObjectWithData`
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Comment: Just to be quick, you just want `username` and `password` as non optionals? I'm a bit lazy to dig through your heap of code.

Comment: My problem is, that the JSON answer I get is an Optional, and therefore not readable

Comment: As the recommended thread, that guy told he was wrong when set "Content-Type" of the request. It must be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`. Your `postString` is form-urlencoded format, so you cannot get it as json. Please check again

Comment: So what do I have to change? Sorry, i´m very new to Swift

Comment: See my updated answer. If there are any error with `setValue` method, please tell me what version of Swift you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You must unwrapping the value when get text from UITextField first, because the `text` property of `UITextField` allow `nil`

```
let username = UsernameTextField.text!
let password = PasswordTextField.text!
```

**Explain more**

When you unwrap the `text` of the UITextField, the `username` and `password` will be `not nil` variable.
The code compare empty should be:

```
if(username.isEmpty || password.isEmpty) {return }
```

If you does not unwrap, when you use this `"\(username)"`, your are try to convert a `nil`able object to string, so the string result will be appended with a "Optional" text.

**To Solve problem with Content-Type for request**

Paste this line to your code. I don't believe that you do not have `setValue` method.

```
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
```

Comment: I already make sure that it´s not nil with `if(username!.isEmpty || password!.isEmpty) {return; }`

Comment: Yes, but the `username!` value is "Optional{"this_is_user_name"}. Please test with my answer first

Comment: Tested with your answer, it remains wrapped as an Optional :/

Comment: Instead of implicitly unwrapping the textfields, it'd be better to do: `let username = UsernameTextField.text ?? ""`.

Comment: Still an Optional. In the similar question I linked it´s said "the problem is not inside the Optional wrapped String but the other http properties", but I don´t know what that means for my code?

Comment: Please explain more what data did you get it is "Optional" in your question

Comment: When I send the username to my database it´s not t4nhpt like it should, instead it appears to be Optional ("t4nhpt")

Comment: Have you tried `let username = UsernameTextField.text ?? ""`? And if you option click `username`, what does it say?

Comment: With `let username = UsernameTextField.text ?? ""` the usernames I store in the database are finally no more an Optional, thank you for this! But I still have the problem, that the JSON answer i get is not readable, thus it´s an Optional

Comment: Glad we got one problem fixed. I'm reading the other post you linked to. Maybe I can help you with that as well.

Comment: I added  `request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")` right before my do catch statement, and nothing changed. Maybe it´s the wrong place? And i really don´t have a `setValue` method, as you can see in the code i posted

Comment: Tested, that method existed here - Swift 2.1. Paste that line after the line `request.HTTPMethod = "POST"` to configure your request.

Comment: I did, and nothing changed. Btw, I am using the latest version of Swift.

Comment: Maybe it helps, this is what I get displayed in the console: "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
Error could not parse JSON: 'Optional(username=MaxMustermann&password=musterpasswort)'
"